# Mongoose nested populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the two following schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String }
  posts: {
    owner: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
    contributor: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
  }
});

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  headline: { type: String, required: true }
  authors: {
    owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    contributors: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  }
});
```

At some point of my application I need to get information about the posts for a specific user. In other words, I need the get the `id` and `headline` of the posts for which an user is the owner or the contributor. However, for the posts for which an user is the contributor, I also need to get information of its author (get the `id`).

I tried to start doing something like this:

```
User.findById(req.params.user_id)
    .populate({ path: 'posts.owner', select: '_id headline' })
    .populate({ path: 'posts.contributor', select: '_id headline'})
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      console.log(user);
    });
```

But I'm not sure on how to continue from here or even if this is the correct approach? Can you give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0):

If your post's headlines don't change frequently you can store alongside with the user document like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  posts: {
    owner: [{
        headline: String,
        post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
    }],
    contributor: [{
        headline: String,
        post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
    }]
  }
});
```

It will create some redundancy, however, it will allow you not to make so many queries just for getting post's headlines.

Also, for consistency you can hook up a presave middleware to your Post schema in order to update headlines in the user's documents. You can do it like this:

```
PostSchema.pre('save', true, function(next, done) {
  next();

  if (!this.isModified('headline')) {
    return done();
  }

  const User = mongoose.model('User');

  return Promise.all([
    User.update({'posts.owner': this._id}, {$set: {'posts.owner.$.headline': this.headline}}, {multi: true}).exec();
    User.update({'posts.contributors': this._id}, {$set: {'posts.contributors.$.headline': this.headline}}, {multi: true}).exec();
  ])
    .then(done)
    .catch(done);
});
```

Comment: My problem is not with the post's headlines... My problem is how can I fetch the owner's information for a post in which a certain user is a contributor! For example, imagine I am a contributor to a post which you created... How would I be able to fetch your information? Because the query would need to go from my user object, fetch your post and from your post get your information!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the information I need in a slightly different manner, using the `async` library.

Here is the code:

```
User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
  if(err) { throw err; }

  // if no user is found
  if(!user) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: { user: 'There is no such user.'} });
    // something bad happened! The requested user does not exist.
  }

  async.parallel({
    owner: function(callback) {
      async.map(user.posts.owner, function(post, callback) {
        Post.findById(post, 'headline').exec(callback);
      }, callback);
    },
    contributor: function(callback) {
      async.map(user.posts.owner, function(post, callback) {
        Post.findById(post, 'headline authors.owner')
            .populate({ path: 'authors.owner', select: 'name' })
            .exec(callback);
      }, callback);
    }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if(err) { throw err; }

    return res.json(results);
  });
});
```